# Dynamically add/remove routees to a router actor

Tags: scala, akka

Would you know a nice way in Akka/Scala to add/remove routees to a Broadcaster router?

I have been looking at the Resizer - but does not meet my needs (I cannot see how to explicitly ask the resizer to resize (add routees) and to remove it seems that you need to send a Poison Pill to the actor which is then removed).

So far, I have a router with a list of ActorRef and I send AddRoutee and RemoveRoutee messages....

**My business case**: I have an actor getting data from the network (via a proxy), and it needs to dispatch this data to independent actors for processing in parallel. Due to the graph nature of the recipients (DAG), the graph can evolve at runtime, vertices/edges being modified, hence the need to add and remove routees

There must be a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks for the pointers.

Example of code I would like Akka to handle:

```
 class MDActor extends Actor {
  @volatile var routees = Set[ActorRef]()

  def receive = {
    case ar: AddRoutee => routees = routees + ar.actorRef
    case rr: RemoveRoutee => routees = routees - rr.actorRef
    case msg => routees.foreach(r => r forward msg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context into what situation(s) happen in your code that result in adding/removing routees from the router?  That kind of info will help in coming up with solutions.

Comment: In your example I would recommend to use Set[ActorRef] instead of List[ActorRef] to prevent routees duplication. And use "forward" instead of "!" to preserve the original sender.

Comment: BTW: no need for @volatile within an actor.

Comment: Decided against the use of actors for this specific business case and fell back to the classic DAG implementation in Scala with graph linearisation

Comment: @RolandKuhn Would it be more "idiomatic" to keep and update the routees through context.become? something like context.become(broadcastReceive(routees + ar.actorRef)) for a broadcastReceive(routees: List[ActorRef]): Receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself lacking a feature in a Router it is a very good time to start thinking in the other direction: what is wrong with the actor code you present? Unless you need to route more than a few million messages per second (which is unlikely given your description) such an actor is precisely the right solution. Routers are a very specialized construct which should not be used as a substitute; only use them when they exactly meet your requirements and you have benchmarked that a normal actor does not suffice.

Comment: Roland, my use case is very specific.. even for "java". So the above pattern works well for what I want my code to do. Indeed, I could have done it the Java way... what would be the fun in that?

Comment: I don’t understand this comment, since I did not talk about Java in my answer. My answer boils down to “you got it figured out, stop looking” ;-)

Comment: Nope. Always looking if there is a better way to do stuff :-)

Comment: @RolandKuhn, Could you clarify "only use them when they exactly meet your requirements and you have benchmarked that a normal actor does not suffice." Are you suggesting that Akka users avoid the standard Router actors provided by Akka when they do exactly meet our requirements but we don't have benchmarks showing that a hand-rolled substitute would meet the requirements? Should we be re-implementing RoundRobinPool, BroadcastGroup, etc., ourselves if we haven't proven that our own implementations can't handle the message rate?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is really a better way than to keep state about the routees and build a new router on every change OR don't use a router and use a plain actor. I looked at this recently too.

Favour immutability - 
The favoured solution, then, is likely going to be to throw away the old router and/or collection and build a new one (router or set/map of actors).

You can just keep track of your actors and not use the router at all - this is a fine solution and recommended in the akka documentation as a simpler alternative to a router. Routers are supposed to have a performance advantage over a full blown actor.

You can build routers with lists of actors as demonstrated here.
Just do this every time there is a change. (source: akka documentation - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)

```
val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val actor3 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val routees = Vector[ActorRef](actor1, actor2, actor3)
val router2 = system.actorOf(Props().withRouter(
  RoundRobinRouter(routees = routees)))
```

Here shows the RoundRobin router but that's not any different than using the broadcast one.

It's a bit more functional to recreate this.

Comment: Does this actually work? I'm seeing errors when instantiating the routers.

Comment: Well, make sure that matches the version of akka you're using :)Also note the one and only Roland Kuhn answered :) We did recreate arrays of actor refs we randomly sent to when building an orchestration/communication library. Recreating routers might be feasible as well.

Comment: Gotcha. I was more looking at the actual compiling of the above statement. I had to use Props.empty.  It probably was a version thing.

Comment: edit: of ya the router creation? If anyone can post a correction I'll edit it for versions today. That was just example code - may have been broken.